# How to create fading shadow lines over gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, shadows

I want to recreate this effect:

[image: effect]

The gradient part at the very top of the mock-up has two line at the downside right-hand corner, with shadow over the gradient and fading inwards.

I want to recreate it with Adobe Illustrator only.

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyPbiGXSGMU&t=10s) on YouTube, but was not really able to achieve my goal.

Can you suggest the easiest way to achieve the effect above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example is made in three steps:

### Background shape

- Fill color #5A00FF

[image: Background shape]

### Top shapes (grouped)

This is a group of three shapes made from a duplicate of the *background shape*

- Fill color #9057ED.
- They all have an **Inner Glow Effect**: dark color, mode Multiply, Opacity: 35%, Blur: 25px.
- The two top shapes are in **Multiply** mode at 40% opacity
- Select the three shapes and group them

[image: Group]

### Mask

- Create a **Mask Shape** a little bigger than the *background shape*
  with a radial gradient from white to black.
- Use the **Gradient Annotator** to transform the gradient area

[image: Mask]

- Select the *group* and the *mask shape* and align them
- From the **Transparency Panel** -> click **Make Mask** -> uncheck Clip
- This is the result:

[image: Masked shape]

- Select this *masked shape* and the *background shape* and align them:

[image: End]

- Edit the mask and modify the gradient to change the transparency